# Setting up R-Studio Appearance

Tags: r, shiny, data-science

I want to make my code easy to read. For example I want to color argument of hist function in red (plot and breaks in red) and their values in blue (FALSE and 20 in blue) -- hist(plot = FALSE, allzips$centile, breaks = 20).
Does anyone know which parameters to set-up in R-studio? I've been playing a lot with the appearances but never get fix.

Thanks,

Kalbi

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Use RStudio and change the appearance, while accepting the syntax highlighting rules.

`Tools` > `Global Options` > `Appearance`

This will present you with a large number of thematic choices.

You can choose the font size, font, and highlighting theme, however you are constrained to the several dozen choices it provides you and the logic of the syntax highlighting is constant, though the specific colors change.

2. Use something other than RStudio which supports fully custom syntax highlighting.

Notepad++ would work for #2. You can click `Language` then setup a custom language syntax highlighting scheme.

Comment: Thank for this recommendation. it has been very helpful.